# yum - list configure flags/options used to compile package

Tags: centos, yum, configure

How can I see a list of flags/options used to configure and compile a certain package in yum, without having to install it first?  Say apache, for example.

```
$ yum list available httpd
    Available Packages
    httpd.x86_64           2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1          base
```

I'm running CentOS 6.3.

**UPDATE**

I followed @jsbillings answer, but first I had to add the CentOS Source repository, as it doesn't seem to be included by default.

Added the following to **/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo**

```
[base-source]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base - Source
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/os/Source
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that if you keep your version of CentOS up to date with the current major version, you may wish to run:

`yum-config-manager --add-repo http://vault.centos.org/centos/6/os/Source`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to grab the package's source RPM.  For example, with apache httpd:

```
yumdownloader --source httpd
```

You can extract just the spec file from the source rpm with:

```
rpm2cpio httpd-version.src.rpm | cpio -i httpd.spec
```

Then, search for the %build section in the RPM spec file.

Sadly, CentOS doesn't appear to keep their spec files in any kind of public repository that I can find on their web site.  You'll have to use the above steps to determine how the package is built.

**edit**: CentOS publishes their specs in Git, so my earlier answer isn’t true now. Here is the httpd spec file:

https://git.centos.org/rpms/httpd/blob/c7/f/SPECS/httpd.spec

Answer (score 3):

I think the place to look is the src package, at the spec file should be a section where the configure command is specified. But I don't know if you could do it without installing it.